# Does it matters where you put the square brackets when creating an Array

Tags: java, arrays

Like `int [] i or int i []` is there any difference
I'm curious

Comment: They are equivalent, but the first-style is [explicitly recommended](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). I suspect the second form is only allowed because that is the C-style, and Java was designed to be easy to learn for people coming from C (even though it is a pretty different language).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ["Brackets are allowed in declarators as a nod to the tradition of C and C++"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2) so your suspicions are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `int[] i` is the same as `int i[]`, but the latter one is discouraged.

See [the official documentation on Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

> However, convention discourages this form; the brackets identify the array type and should appear with the type designation.